# Where should I place the php code for inserting data into MySql Server from Wordpress site

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, wordpress

I have a created a custom form in Wordpress site using the html code. I wanted to insert the data entered into it to my local db using the given php code. I wanted to know where should I place this php code so that it gets executed when the Submit button is clicked. (Also should I need to make any modification to the php code for the same?)

### `PHP CODE`

```
<?php 
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php');
  $Name = $formData['Name'];// set form data in variable
  $Aadhar = $formData['Aadhar'];
  $Mobile = $formData['Mobile'];
  $Company = $formData['Company'];
 $Description = $formData['Description'];

  global $wpdb;

  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_test_form ( Name, Aadhar,Mobile,Company,Description ) 
            VALUES ( %s, %s,%s,%s,%s)",$Name,$Aadhar,$Mobile,$Company,$Description)
    );      
?>
```

Comment: Please, [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code properly

Comment: Yes, I have formatted the code.